# How to use 1 for loop in a method in stead of using the same for loop over and over again

Tags: c#

Since i'm still learning C# i've made an exercise but it seems like i'm using the same code over and over again.
I do realize I have to use a helper method to get rid of the 'useless' code.

How can I put my for loops into a helper method ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NewTryoutExamen
{
    class Ploeg
    {
        private List<Werknemer> werknemers = new List<Werknemer>();

        public void VoegWerknemerToe(Werknemer w)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < werknemers.Count; i++)
            {
                if (w.Id == werknemers[i].Id)
                    throw new DuplicateWaitObjectException();
            }

            werknemers.Add(w);
        }

        public uint Prestatie(uint werknemerId, uint hoeveelheid)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < werknemers.Count; i++)
            {
                if (werknemerId == werknemers[i].Id)
                    return werknemers[i].VoegVerkopenToe(hoeveelheid);
            }
            throw new KeyNotFoundException();
        }


        public uint GeefAantalEenheden(uint werknemerId)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < werknemers.Count; i++)
            {
                if (werknemerId == werknemers[i].Id)
                    return werknemers[i].AantalEenheden;
            }
            throw new KeyNotFoundException();
        }

        public double GeefTotaalLoon(uint werknemerId)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < werknemers.Count; i++)
            {
                if (werknemerId == werknemers[i].Id)
                    return werknemers[i].TotaalLoon();
            }
            throw new KeyNotFoundException();
        }

        public Werknemer ToonWerknemerDetails(uint werknemerId)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < werknemers.Count; i++)
            {
                if (werknemerId == werknemers[i].Id)
                    return werknemers[i];
            }
            throw new KeyNotFoundException(); 
        }

        public double Basisloon(uint werknemerId)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < werknemers.Count; i++)
            {
                if (werknemerId == werknemers[i].Id)
                {
                    return werknemers[i].Basisloon;
                }
            }
            throw new KeyNotFoundException();
        }


        public double Commissie(uint werknemerId)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < werknemers.Count; i++)
            {
                if (werknemerId == werknemers[i].Id)
                {
                    return werknemers[i].Commissie;
                }
            }
            throw new KeyNotFoundException();
        }


        public override string ToString()
        {
            string res = "";
            string Id;

            for (int i = 0; i < werknemers.Count; i++)
            {
                Id = string.Format("{0:0000}", werknemers[i].Id);
                res += Id + " - " + werknemers[i].Naam + " " + werknemers[i].Voornaam + " ( eenheden: " + werknemers[i].AantalEenheden + ")" + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Please specify only the code's purpose, not a specific request, in the title.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/22222)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely look into [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx). It saves alot of space.

A few reworks;

```
for (int i = 0; i < werknemers.Count; i++)
{
    if (w.Id == werknemers[i].Id)
       throw new DuplicateWaitObjectException();
}
```

becomes

```
if(werknemers.Any(wn => w.Id == wn.Id)
{
    throw new DuplicateWaitObjectException();
}
```

And

```
for (int i = 0; i < werknemers.Count; i++)
{
    if (werknemerId == werknemers[i].Id)
        return werknemers[i].VoegVerkopenToe(hoeveelheid);
}
```

becomes

```
return werknemers.Where(w => w.Id == werknemerId).FirstOrDefault().VoegVerkopenToe(hoeveelheid);
```

I'll leave the rest as an excercise :)

Comment: I got an error with the next one ... return werknemers.Where(w => werknemerId == w.Id).FirstOrDefault().AantalEenheden;
   throw new KeyNotFoundException();

Comment: @Awa it helps if you tell us what error it is :)

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @Awa I was hoping you'd figure that out by yourself, therefore I am leaving it for exercise. A big hint: `FirstOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 4):

There is a pre-built method for testing if any element matches a condition:

```
if(werknemers.Any(werknemer => w.Id == werknemer.Id)){
    throw new DuplicateWaitObjectException();
}
werknemers.Add(w);
```

However you look up every werknemer a lot based on the ID. You should use a [`Dictionary<uint, Werknemer>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead which includes methods to [check if a key is already used](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx) and a way to get the object back with the key:

```
public double Commissie(uint werknemerId)
{
    if(werknemers.ContainsKey(werknemerId))
        return werknemers[werknemerId].Commissie;
    }
    throw new KeyNotFoundException();
}
```